# JBoss AS7 JNDI Datasource Database pooling not really pooling

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

I have a MySQL datasource setup with a min pool size set to 5 but if I do a "show processlist;" in MySQL I only see one connect?

Why is JBoss not opening the 5 min connections?